# Python: Return max 8 value random by array 2-D

Tags: python

I would like to extract maximum `x` values ​​in different positions and save their position.

```
[[ 5, 57, 66, 59, 26],
 [23, 66, 97, 96, 33],
 [31, 63, 69, 55, 20],
 [ 2, 77, 37, 85, 40],
 [87, 94, 43, 92, 44],
]
```

Thanks

Comment: 1) it's not clear what you want. Please include your desired output. Based on what you've said, it sounds like `numpy.argmax` would be where to start

Comment: for example i want 8 values with "replace = false"
1) value 5 position 0,0 
2) value 94 position 4,1 ... for up to 8 values. I have to be able to work with those values.

Comment: Use the edit button and type out the actual array you expect given this input and include the code of your failed attempts

Answer (score 1):

Using `max` with a `range` over an array is one way to get the index of the maximum element:

```
>>> [max(range(len(row)), key=row.__getitem__) for row in m]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Another option would be to use `index` after getting the max element itself (this is slightly less efficient because now you're scanning each row twice, but the difference is a constant factor):

```
>>> [row.index(max(row)) for row in m]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not totally clear if you want `n` randomly chosen or `n` largest items. I include solutions for both interpretations because they are very similar

Assuming you want 8 randomly chosen items from a 2D array and their positions

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
[[ 5, 57, 66, 59, 26],
[23, 66, 97, 96, 33],
[31, 63, 69, 55, 20],
[ 2, 77, 37, 85, 40],
[87, 94, 43, 92, 44]])
```

Create a random boolean matrix to choose the items

```
how_many = 8
choices = [True] * how_many + [False] * (len(x.ravel()) - how_many)
choices = np.random.permutation(choices).reshape(x.shape)
x[choices]
```

Out:

```
array([66, 59, 23, 33, 63, 69, 20, 40])
```

To get their positions

```
positions_2D  = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.flatnonzero(choices), x.shape)).T
positions_2D
```

Out:

```
array([[0, 2],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 2],
       [2, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

To get the chosen items by 2D coordinates

```
x[positions_2D[:,0], positions_2D[:,1]]
```

Out:

```
array([66, 59, 23, 33, 63, 69, 20, 40])
```

---

If you want the 8 largest items it is the same approach without the boolean array to choose the items

```
top_8_positions_in_2D = np.vstack(np.unravel_index(x.argsort(None), x.shape)).T[:-9:-1]
x[top_8_positions_in_2D[:,0], top_8_positions_in_2D[:,1]]
```

Out:

```
array([97, 96, 94, 92, 87, 85, 77, 69])
```

To get their 2D coordinates

```
top_8_positions_in_2D
```

Out:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 3],
       [4, 1],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 0],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 1]])
```